# WinAppDriver support of custom elements on Windows Desktop

Tags: testing, appium, winappdriver, appium-desktop

colleagues.
We try to automate our old style win32 mfc application with WinAppDriver + Appium.
Mainly, it works, but we would like to know: is it possible to extend a functionality and add a support for custom gui elements.
For example, we have a grid class where we want to know a number of columns/rows, read\write cell conent, etc.
Any links, articles are very appriciate.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All available controls can be seen in Session.PageSource.

If you can access the app source then you can add automation properties to controls to make it available. There are no other solutions that exist for now.